# Android Accessibility API: Fill up multiple EditText or move to next EditText

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm making an auto-fill type accessibility service for android. I read the documentation and did some googling and it's still confusing to me. I got only one edittext to fill up the text. Whenever I try to move to the next edittext, it doesn't work. Is there a way to access all the edit text a once? Anyone has a solution for this?

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    final int eventType = event.getEventType();
    String eventText = null;
    switch(eventType) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            eventText = "Clicked: ";
            break;
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
            eventText = "Focused " + event.getItemCount() +":";
            break;
    }

    eventText = eventText + event.getContentDescription();

    System.out.println("Accessibility On Accessibility Event");
    Log.i("Test", "Custom Accessibility On Accessibility Event");

    // Do something nifty with this text, like speak the composed string
    // back to the user.
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eventText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //let's try this
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
    if(event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "Howdy");
        nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);

        nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY);
//            event.setAction(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    System.out.println("CustomAccessibility On Interrupt");
    Log.i("Custom", "CustomAccessibility On Interrupt");
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    //super.onServiceConnected();

    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "onServiceConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("CustomAccessibility On Service Connected");
    Log.i("Custom", "CustomAccessibility On Service Connected");

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();

    // Set the type of events that this service wants to listen to.  Others
    // won't be passed to this service.
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED |
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED;

    // If you only want this service to work with specific applications, set their
    // package names here.  Otherwise, when the service is activated, it will listen
    // to events from all applications.


    // Set the type of feedback your service will provide.
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_VISUAL;

    // Default services are invoked only if no package-specific ones are present
    // for the type of AccessibilityEvent generated.  This service *is*
    // application-specific, so the flag isn't necessary.  If this was a
    // general-purpose service, it would be worth considering setting the
    // DEFAULT flag.

    // info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;

    info.notificationTimeout = 100;

    this.setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find fix for the issue?